# how do I know if the BIOS or the OS is throttling my CPU?

Tags: power-management, cpu, bios

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 18.04. I've been sold a second hand Dell Precision M6700 Laptop with an under-powered power adaptor.

Apparently the BIOS is able to recognise this condition and I read somewhere that it will apply an extreme throttle to the CPU.

I wonder please how can I check if the throttle is on or not.

Many thanks :)